# Find trapezoid height if all sides are given

Tags: geometry

What is the formula to find height of trapezoid if all sides are given?

For example if lengths of sides are:
a: 11, b: 3, c: 7, d: 6

How would we calculate length of height (h)?

What is the formula for this? [trapezoid](https://ibb.co/1XF1FSJ)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm asking for formula for height of trapezoid.

Comment: here is the picture of trapezoid https://ibb.co/1XF1FSJ

Comment: I don't have your answer, but I can sketch your trapezoid well enough to convince me that it exists! A=(0,0) D = (5.38275, 2.66233), C = (12.38275, 2.66233) and B=(11,0). If i find time, I will look at this further.  It's not hard.  Just needs solution to a few circle equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ and $c$ are bases, as in your picture. Then height of trapezoid is the same as height of triangle with sides $|a-c|$, $b$ and $d$. You can find the height of triangle from sides using two formulae of triangle area:
$$S=\sqrt{p(p-|a-c|)(p-b)(p-d)}=\frac{h|a-c|}{2},$$ where $p=\frac{|a-c|
+b+d}{2}$.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the height is $x$ then $11=\sqrt{6^2-x^2}+7\pm\sqrt{3^2-x^2}$.

Comment: look at this calculator https://www.mathepower.com/en/trapezoid.php