# How to find the distance from the intersection point of a trapezoid's diagonals to its midline?

Tags: geometry

In an arbitrary trapezoid $ABCD$ with bases $BC$ and $AD$, the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at the point $O$. The segment $MN$ is such that $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $CD$. Knowing $AB=a$, $BC=b$, $CD=c$, and $AD=d$, find the distance from $O$ to $MN$.

I suspect it can be derived from the coordinates of the vertices of a trapezoid (i.e. put the point $A$ at $(0;0)$ and $D$ at $(d;0)$, then two other coordinates can be uniquely expressed; find the line equation for each diagonal and find their common point; find the line equation for $MN$ using the midpoint formula for $AB$ and $CD$; find the distance from $O$ to $MN$ by ready-made formula, and that is possibly colossal in calculations), but I'm looking for more elegant (which means shorter, more elementary and possibly involving Euclidean geometry) solutions, if possible.

Comment: Your question needs more clarification. Is the trapezoid considered arbitrary? What is generally known about the trapezoid? What lengths of segments or  angles are assumed to be known?

Comment: "I suspect it can be derived" What did you try? https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @greyls edits made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the two triangles marked $S$ and $T$ below:

[image]

Since they are similar
$$\frac{d(O,AD)}{d(O,BC)}=\frac db$$
and since the height $h=d(O,AD)+d(O,BC)$ [can be computed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409579) from $a,b,c,d$ we can compute $d(O,AD)$ and $d(O,BC)$ individually:
$$d(O,AD)=\frac{dh}{b+d},d(O,BC)=\frac{bh}{b+d}$$ Then the desired quantity $d(O,MN)$ is
$$\frac 12|d(O,AD)-d(O,BC)|=\frac{|b-d|h}{2(b+d)}$$

Comment: Thus, the greater the difference between lengths of bases is, the farther is O from MN?

Comment: Then out of curiosity what is the maximum distance between $O$ and $MN$?

Comment: If it shrinks to a point, it is no longer a trapezoid, thus I guess we consider the infinitely small base, and the distance is infinitely close to $0.5\times h$. Thus, $0 \leq d(O,MN) \lt 0.5\times h$. Am I getting this right?

Comment: I guess I was a bit wrong here. $d(O,MN)$ cannot be zero, as if it is, the bases must be equal, and that makes the quadrilateral not a trapezoid, but a parallelogram.

Comment: @Rusurano I consider all parallelograms trapeziums.

Comment: Then are all triangles trapeziums with one of bases having length 0? :)

Comment: @Rusurano Yes..